# AutoFill method of the Range class failed

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am encountering the "Auto Fill method of Range class failed" COM exception while trying to auto fill a excel using C#.
Need your help to resolve this problem. Since I have tried multiple ways to achieve it but failing.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRange = null;
oRange = workSheet.get_Range("E7");
oRange.AutoFill(workSheet.get_Range("E130", "E131"));
```

Am i calling it in wrong way?

Please suggest, if you have an alternative of it.

Answer (score 6):

The destination parameter of the autofill method states that the destination range must include the source range.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195345(v=office.15).aspx

Your source is E1, the destination is E130:E131, so yours does not.

If your destination was E1:E131 instead for example, that would work.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the doubt. now it's working as expected. E1:E131

Answer (score 1):

I have resolve it by an alternative;

```
((Range)workSheet.Cells[oEntities.RowCount, 5]).FillDown();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but still did not find a working example in the existing answers.
Following @steve16351 answer, the destination range must include the source range:

Given a range of A2:A10, we want to auto fill the next column B2:B10.

So our destination range needs to be A2:B10.

```
Range source = sheet.Range["A2:A10"];
Range destination = sheet.Range[range, sheet.Cells[source.Row, source.Offset[0,1].Column]]; // returns A2:B10
source.AutoFill(destination);
```